# Docker: Is it possible to share data between 2 containers without a volume?

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 containers: `web` and `nginx`. When I build `web` container, static assets for frontend are generated within the container.

Now, I want to share those assets between `web` and `nginx` without using a volume on the host machine. Otherwise, I'll have to build those static assets on the host side and then include as a volume into the `web` container and share it with `nginx` container. This is undesirable from my build system's standpoint.

Is there a way to build static assets in the `web` container and then share them with `nginx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Otherwise, I'll have to build those static assets on the host side and then include as a volume into the web container and share it with nginx container.

This statement seems incorrect.

If the static assets are generated as part of the build process, then just mount a volume on top of that directory at runtime.  Docker will take care of copying the underlying content into the volume, after which you can access it in your nginx container using `--volumes-from`.

For example, if I start with this `Dockerfile` for my web container:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --update darkhttpd
COPY assets /assets
CMD ["darkhttpd", "/assets"]
```

I now have a directory `/assets` that contains my static assets.  If I
run this image as:

```
docker run -v /assets --name web web
```

Then `/assets` will (a) be a volume and (b) contain the contents of
the `/assets` directory.

Now you can start an nginx container and share this data with it:

```
docker run --volumes-from web nginx
```

The nginx container will have a `/assets` directory that contains your
static assets.

I've put together a small example [here](https://github.com/larsks/irc-example-bob).

Comment: Ah, so I don't have to map a volume to the host machine's directory? Volume can be independent of the host? Thank you for your detailed answer, larsks.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/ is a good read about managing data in docker.

Comment: RE: "so I don't have to map a volume to the host machine's directory?" -> if you don't mount a host volume, you will just lose the data when you delete the container. You cna still mount a local volume in the static asset container and then mount the --volume-from on the nginx container.

Comment: @MrE That's not entirely correct.  The `docker volume` command lets you create persistent volumes that are not bound to the lifetime of a container.

Comment: @larsk: yes that' true. I meant that if you use a container (not a volume) as your storage (i.e. generated content), it will be gone if your delete the container, but indeed you can use a Volume.

Comment: Actually, even for anonymous volumes create via `-v`, they won't get deleted when you delete the container unless you provide the `-v` option to `docker rm`.  Try `docker volume ls; docker run -v /foo --name test busybox true; docker rm test; docker volume ls`.  You've deleted the container but the new volume still exists.

Comment: Does such an approach mean, that a volume with assets should be deleted between builds? Because on initial creation of volume contents of `assets` from container will really be copied into newly created volume, but if a new version of code contains new/changed assets, which will be copied into a container, these will not be copied into a volume, because volume exists already and contents of a volume will replace the contents of container on mount.

Comment: As far as I know, this is a naive/incomplete solution, for the reasons @ViktorLivakivskyi mentioned. In other words, it would only work the first time `web` is ever run and never again. In the real world, at some point, `web` is going to have a second version. (I would love to be proven wrong, though.)